# SSIS sql command two '?' mapping one parameter

Tags: ssis

I am in the middle of SSIS sync two tables.
The problem happens while updating with mapping.
I separated inserting data and updating data. It is supposed to be conditional updating. Only update the rows which are different from the source table.

I added OLE DB Command and wrote sql.

UPDATE LocationSearch.dbo.AMENITY
SET
[AMENITY_TYPE]=?

,[AMENITY_NAME]=?

,[FITNET_AMENITY_NAME]=?

,[EXCLUDE_MIGRATION_FROM_FITNET_TO_PLPORTAL]=?

WHERE ([AMENITY_ID]=?) and (([AMENITY_TYPE]!=?) or ([AMENITY_NAME]!=?) or ([FITNET_AMENITY_NAME]!=?) or ([EXCLUDE_MIGRATION_FROM_FITNET_TO_PLPORTAL]!=?))

some of the question marks are the same parameters. Therefore causes the mapping problem for one parameter cannot map two column names.

Is there any sql command to avoid this mapping issue or other solutions?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this using stored procedure executed with OLE DB Command.
So you can assign just the parameters you need (are available), but inside the SP use the parameters as much times you have to.

BR